# Let items in ListBox depend on which item is selected in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a little WPF application with a ComboBox where the user can choose from a list of items. I also have a ListBox where I want the available items in the ListBox to depend on which item is currently selected in the ComboBox.

Say the ComboBox has the following options: "Fruits" and "Vegetables".
If I select "Fruits", the ListBox will contain "Apple", "Banana", "Pear" etc, and if I select "Vegetables" it will contain "Carrot", "Potato" etc.

This is just a fictional example, but covers what I need. In my app - both the data for the ComboBox and whatever is to be put in the ListBox will come from an external data source.

How can I do this? I have already done the binding of my view model to the view and populated the ComboBox from the data source, but I need the content of the ListBox to reflect the selected option in the ComboBox.

Comment: In what format do you get the data for the `ListBox`?

Comment: ObservableCollection<string>

Comment: So you have no actual knowledge about the mapping, which `ObservableCollection<string>` belongs to which member of the `ComboBox` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make 2 lists and bind one of them to your listbox according to the selection. e.g:

```
List <string> Fruits=new List<string>(){"apple","banana",..};
List <string> Vegetables=new List<string>(){"tomato","Potato",..};
```

and in your Combox selection change event:

```
private void OComboBox1Changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    if (ComboBox1.Selected.Item=...)
    {
        listbox1.ItemsSource=Fruits;
    }
    else
    {
      listbox1.ItemsSource=Vegetables;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a viewmodel, why do you solve this with code behind? I think this should be handled in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a DependencyProperty to your viewmodel which contains the SelectedItem

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItem",
        typeof(YourType),
        typeof(YourViewModel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemChanged)
        )
    );

    public YourType SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (YourType)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
```

(Replace YourType with the type of Vegetables/Fruits and YourViewModel with the type of your viemodel)

and bind this to your Combobox SelectedItem in XAML.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
```

You also need to define a method to handle the PropertyChangedCallback:

```
    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the listbox item source here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

View:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}"
    Width="200"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lst}" Grid.Row="1">
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selectedOption;

    public string SelectedOption
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedOption;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedOption = value;
            this.UpdateOnOptionChange();
        }
    }
    
    public List<string> Options
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> lst
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Options = new List<string>() { "Fruits", "Vegetables" };
        this.lst = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    private void UpdateOnOptionChange()
    {
        this.lst.Clear();
        if (this.selectedOption == "Fruits")
        {
            this.lst.Add("Apple");
            this.lst.Add("Banana");
            this.lst.Add("Pear");
        }
        else if (this.selectedOption == "Vegetables")
        {
            this.lst.Add("Carrot");
            this.lst.Add("Potato");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyOnPropertyChange(string astrPropertyName)
    {
        if (null != this.PropertyChanged)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(astrPropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```